# Time complexity of Math.sqrt Java

Tags: java, time-complexity

What is time-complexity of math.sqrt implementation in Java ?
Java has time-complexity implemented in some technique whose, time-complexity I am trying to determine.

Comment: Please try to elaborate on what your problem is. The description you gave is hard to grasp.

Comment: I'd imagine it would use Newton's method (or some other similar numerical analysis method).

Comment: I would suggest to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232629/what-is-time-complexity-and-how-to-find-it
It's very well-explained and can give you good knowledge of what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, Java attempts to use the "smart-power" algorithm, which results in a time-complexity of O(log n).
[Smart power Algorithm](http://www.ica.luz.ve/cstufano/CursoEDyA/Libros/Java%20Collections%20-%20Watt,%20Brown/files/00042___ffb6f390f1f95d973b1e4651c2ebbe5d.pdf)

Also, it appears that in different cases, you could end up with different complexities; [Why is multiplied many times faster than taking the square root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112162/why-is-multiplied-many-times-faster-than-taking-the-square-root)

Comment: from the [source code](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/StrictMath-source.html), Math.sqrt will use bit operation trick and directly determine every bit in sqrt(n), which is at most O(64) ~ O(1)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is implemented by delegating to the sqrt method StrictMath which is a native method.

Thus it seems the answer would be implementation specific.

Strictly speaking it is O(1).  In theory (but obviously not practice), we could iterate over all doubles and find the maximum time.

In addition, the time complexity of Math.sqrt(n) does not **directly** depend on n but instead on the amount of space needed to represent n which for doubles should be constant.

Comment: This should be [the definition of `StrictMath.sqrt`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825221/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-javas-square-root-function)